# how to keep text as it is while parent is fliped?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: before hover] this is before hover

[image: after hover] i want this is after hover

i want keep the text horizontal like this **[menu]** after rotating the **li** on hover. how to do with simple solution. I saw some examples but not understand it. jQuery is also ok for it. Please help, Thank you.

```css
section#fourth{
 margin:auto;
 width: 550px;
}
section#fourth li {
 padding: 8px 10px;
 transition: all .5s;
 background: brown;
 display: block;
 width: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
}
section#fourth li a{
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;

}

section#fourth li:hover{
 border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 


<section id="fourth">
 <h2>Example</h2>
 <nav>
  <ul class="list-inline">
   <li><a href="#">M<br>e<br>n<br>u<br></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">M<br>e<br>n<br>u<br></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">M<br>e<br>n<br>u<br></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">M<br>e<br>n<br>u<br></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">M<br>e<br>n<br>u<br></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: <a> tag?? you should close them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `span` tag for all alphabets, rotate `span` on hover of li via `transform: rotate(90deg);`.

Update HTML & CSS, i have remove `<br>` from `li`.

**HTML**

```
<section id="fourth">
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <nav>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><span>e</span><span>n</span><span>u</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><span>e</span><span>n</span><span>u</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><span>e</span><span>n</span><span>u</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><span>e</span><span>n</span><span>u</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><span>e</span><span>n</span><span>u</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

**Updated CSS**

```
section#fourth{
    margin:auto;
    width: 550px;
}
section#fourth li {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    transition: all .5s;
    background: brown;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
section#fourth li a{
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;

}

section#fourth li:hover{
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
section#fourth li span{
  display:block;
}
section#fourth li:hover span{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
section#fourth li:hover a{ 
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Check [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u96L2rvg/3/)

Comment: is it possible to stick non-rotated li to rotated li? because there is some gap after hover. i want to remove it

Comment: @sagarkodte Yes possible

Comment: @sagarkodte please let me know if is it okay or not??

Comment: Which gap are you talking about?? a gap between text or else??

Comment: after fliped li there is gap on top and bottom between non-flip li .. got it?

Comment: You want to stick li after hover if m right then check this link & let me know : https://jsfiddle.net/u96L2rvg/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111914/discussion-between-sagar-kodte-and-sunil-gehlot).

Answer (score 2):

put your each text into `<span>` tag and rotate it using same method

```js
$(".list-inline li").hover(
   
   function() {
     
      $(this).find('a span').attr('class', 'span');
     
     if($(this).index() == 0)
        $(this).css('margin-bottom', '-32px');
     else if($(this).index() == ($(this).parent('ul').children().length) - 1)
        $(this).css('margin-top', '-32px');
     else
        {
          $(this).css('margin-bottom', '-32px');
          $(this).css('margin-top', '-34px');
        }
   },
   
  function() {
    
    if($(this).index() == 0)
       $(this).css('margin-bottom', '3px');
    else if($(this).index() == ($(this).parent('ul').children().length) - 1)
      $(this).css('margin-top', '3px');
    else
      {
        $(this).css('margin-bottom', '3px');
        $(this).css('margin-top', '3px');
      }
});
```

```css
section#fourth {
  margin: auto;
  width: 550px;
}
section#fourth li {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  transition: all .5s;
  background: brown;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
section#fourth li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
section#fourth li:hover {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
}
.span {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section id="fourth">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <nav>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><br><span>e</span><br><span>n</span><br><span>u</span><br></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><br><span>e</span><br><span>n</span><br><span>u</span><br></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><br><span>e</span><br><span>n</span><br><span>u</span><br></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><br><span>e</span><br><span>n</span><br><span>u</span><br></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>M</span><br><span>e</span><br><span>n</span><br><span>u</span><br></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: is it possible to stick non-rotated li to rotated li? because there is some gap after hover. i want to remove it

Comment: Yes, It is possible. See I have edited above code snippet to make it work

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this we can use the properties `word-break: break-all` and `letter-spacing` instead of adding multiple `span` tags to separate each word.

What `word-break: break-all` will do to your `<a>` tag is that it will break words between any 2 letters if they do not fit in their container's width.

After breaking each word, we will add the property `letter-spacing` to increase the space between characters after we hover the parent element.

Edit: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hxu4y27/)

HTML

```
   <section id="fourth">
        <h2>Example</h2>
        <nav>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
    section#fourth{
        margin:auto;
        width: 550px;
    }
    section#fourth li {
        padding: 8px 10px;
        transition: all .5s;
        background: brown;
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }  


  section#fourth li a {
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        word-break: break-all;
        display: block;
        letter-spacing: 10px;
}

   section#fourth li:hover{
        border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        min-height: 96px;
    }

    section#fourth li:hover a{
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      word-break: normal;
    }
```